# Input string was not in a correct format convert.todouble()

Tags: c#, windows

I am getting this error. This is the code

```
double totalfees = Convert.ToDouble(textBox12.Text);
double paidfees = Convert.ToDouble(textBox13.Text);
double pendingfees = totalfees - paidfees;

label20.Text = pendingfees.ToString();
```

what should I do?

Comment: What inputs are present in textbox12 and 13? On which line you are facing error?

Comment: What values are in the textboxes?

Comment: numeric input values are present in textboxes. I m getting this error on line"double totalfees=convert.todouble(textbox12.text);"

Comment: @AshwiniNemade You aren't converting, you are *parsing* text into a *double*. Different cultures use different decimal and thousand separators. Post the *actual text in the input boxes*.

Comment: @AshwiniNemade no, numeric input values are not present in the textboxes which is why you got that error. `1,35` is valid in some cultures, invalid in others. *Post the text*

Comment: @AshwiniNemade or the user typed something really unusual like `10,00,00` which is valid in only *one* culture.

Comment: user is leaving that space blank and then accessing textbox13 thats why he is getting this error

Comment: use TryParse instead, if it return false assign default value 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below.

```
double totalfees = Convert.ToDouble(textBox12.Text.ToString().Trim());
double paidfees = Convert.ToDouble(textBox13.TextToString().Trim());
double pendingfees = totalfees - paidfees;

label20.Text = pendingfees.ToString();
```

Or use `double.TryParse()` instead. It's a better way to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Before using parse method use TryParse like below code:

```
double totalFees;
if (Double.TryParse(textBox12.Text, out totalFees) == false)
    throw new Exception("Invalid value unable to parse into double");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since user can put *any* string as a response (e.g. `"bla-bla-bla"`) we should *validate* the input; let's *extract method* for this:

```
private static bool ReadDouble(Control control, bool allowEmpty, out double value) {
  if (allowEmpty && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.Text)) {
    value = 0.0;

    return true;
  }

  bool result = double.TryParse(control.Text, out value);

  if (!result) {
    if (control.CanFocus)
      control.Focus();

    MessageBox.Show("Invalid value; floating point value expected", 
                     Application.ProductName, 
                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                     MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Then you can put a simple

```
if (ReadDouble(textBox12, false, out var totalfees) && 
    ReadDouble(textBox13, true, out var paidfees))
  label20.Text = (totalfees - paidfees).ToString();
else
  label20.Text = "???";
```